# Как вывести записи из таблицы Книги, при условии что данная запись есть в другой таблице с статусом 2

Tags: sql-server

У меня есть таблица **книги**, таблица **выдачи**

Необходимо вывести все записи из таблицы **Книги** при условии:

1. Книга в таблице Books не имеет свою запись в таблице выдачи,
   если имеет то только те записи которые имеют статус 2
2. То есть должно получится вот так, книга с id 5 по 14 должны выводится, а так как у книг с id 1 и 3 статус вы таблице выдача 1 , то данные записи о книге не должны выводится.

что в таблице **выдача** книга имеет статус 2 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал вот так, но выводит только одну строку

```
    select * from Books
where Id = (Select IdBook From Extraditions
where IdStatus = 2)
```

Ожидаемый результат вот такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, если книга есть в таблице выдачи с статусом 1, то она должна при выводе отсеиваться, а если 2, то выводится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM Extraditions
                   WHERE Extraditions.IdBook = Books.Id
                     AND Extraditions.IdStatus <> 2 )
```

Наличие любой связанной записи со статусом, не равным 2, блокирует возврат записи. Иначе (есть только связанные записи со статусом 2, или связанных записей нет вообще)  запись возвращается.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score -1):

Можно через JOIN:

```
select * from Books inner join Extraditions
  on Extraditions.IdBook = Books.Id
  and Extraditions.IdStatus = 2
```

Comment: 1)Книга в таблице Books не имеет свою запись в таблице выдачи, если имеет то только те записи которые имеют статус 2

2)То есть должно получится вот так, книга с id 5 по 14 должны выводится, а так как у книг с id 1 и 3 статус в таблице выдача 1 , то данные записи о книге не должны выводится.